# Jumbled writing under a post

Tags: posts

>
>

> The websites we have are Wordpress ones. I add new things on okay but 
>   the issue is a glitch that has always been on it.
>
> If you look on this page after the post the writing underneath is like 
>   two lines on top of each other.
>
> http://westlancspositiveliving.org.uk/2012/01/reindeer-dash-important-news/

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Edward.

Answer (score 1):

Find in your CSS (on line 915 of style.css for the Twenty Ten theme):

```
#nav-below {
   margin: -18px 0 0 0;
}
```

change to:

```
#nav-below {
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

What's happening is that the #nav-below is getting pushed up into your other content due to the minus. It's not a glitch either or relevant to WordPress itself, someone just made some mistakes when styling the CSS.

Comment: Tried that. But on our site it says its using- Twenty Ten Child I can edit Twenty Ten Theme and Twenty Elebven theme. If I look on Twenty Ten Child its not the same. Thanks.

Comment: The file is here: http://westlancspositiveliving.org.uk/wpcms/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css